# Why combiner input records are more than mapper output records?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, combiners, mappers

Combiner works on output records of mapper. If the mapper output records are fed to the combiner then why are my combiner input records are more than mapper output records?

I got these 80 records extra.I have no idea from where they came & what their value is.

Yarn dump of Mapreduce:

```
 Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=80000000
            Map output records=80000000
            Map output bytes=2560000000
            Map output materialized bytes=80
            Input split bytes=220
            Combine input records=80000083
            Combine output records=85
            Reduce input groups=1
            Reduce shuffle bytes=80
            Reduce input records=2
            Reduce output records=3
            Spilled Records=87
            Shuffled Maps =2
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=2
            GC time elapsed (ms)=4124
            CPU time spent (ms)=90530
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=573521920
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2509766656
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=411041792
```

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171965/why-is-the-number-of-combiner-input-records-more-than-the-number-of-outputs-of-m

Comment: @VigneshI thanks for that. I calculate the count of map outputs in my combiner & find a total count at reducer across all mappers. So, is this the reason I'm getting a wrong count at reducer?

Comment: What type of computations can't be calculated at combiner? Since, the reducer output is irrespective of the number of times a combiner runs.

Comment: That will not be the reason. If you want to count the records then your logic is fine, emit 1 from mapper, and then summing up map output in combiner then summing up all the results in reducer.

Comment: This blog will explain you in detail when to use and not to use a combiner. http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/14/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-4-to-use-or-not-to-use-a-combiner/